# How to dynamicaly create ons-tabbar in page

Tags: javascript, onsen-ui, onsen-ui2

I am trying to generate tabbar pages dynamically in my app. I tried generate elements with `ons.createElement()` and `document.createElement()`. But it don't render the pages. Only tabbar, or first page and not the second. Do you know how to dynamicaly render tabbar in onsen ui?

I am using Onsen UI v2.10.8

Many thanks and have a nice day.

EDIT Last code I tried:

```
RenderTabButtons(view, $page, cb) {
    let data = [];
    let onsEle = `
      <ons-tab
        id="rdMainTab"
        page="rdMain.html"
        label="Main"
        icon="ion-home, material:md-home"
        active
      >
      </ons-tab>
    `;
    data.push(onsEle);
    let onsMapEle = null;
    if (view.mapVisible) {
      onsMapEle = `
        <ons-tab
          id="rdMapTab"
          page="rdDetailMap.html"
          label="Map"
          icon="ion-home, material:md-home"
        >
        </ons-tab>
      `;
      data.push(onsMapEle);
    }

    let wrap = `
      <ons-tabbar
        swipeable
        position="auto"
        id="reservation-detail-tabbar"
        class="x-margin-top"
      >`;
    for (let a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {
      wrap += data[a];
    }
    wrap += '</ons-tabbar>';

    $page[0].appendChild(ons.createElement(wrap));
    cb();
  }
```

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: I will try to clean up last experiments, little bit and will post it.

Comment: @Hkachhia  Added last code i tried, but I am also open to new ways to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that works fine. Just append it to the element with the class name "tab-bar" and don't forget to run ons.compile() on the element:

```
var $tab = $('<ons-tab  label="Label" ></ons-tab>');
$('.tab-bar').append($tab);
ons.compile($tab[0]);



<ons-tabbar>
  <ons-tab label="Tab 1" active></ons-tab>
  <ons-tab label="Tab 2"></ons-tab>
</ons-tabbar>
```

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot, I am using version 2 which looks like don't have method compile.